# Index.html shows blank page after building svelte(not kit) app with npm run build in svelte

Tags: javascript, npm, svelte

But the `npm run dev` server shows the default counter app that is built. But when i build plain html css javascript with `npm run build` in dist folder. then run the index.html by clicking it, it shows blank page. Event though the index.html has this content

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + Svelte</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-98081fa1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index-65be3931.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

But npm run dev server has the counter app that you get if you initialize with `npm init vite`
then

```
$ npm install
$ npm run dev
```

this is in svelte not sveltekit.

Comment: `npm run build` does not just magically build a Svelte application. It's just a script defined in `package.json` that executes some build tool. You should always include what those build tools are and what the actual command behind `build` is, if you ask such a question.

Comment: @H.B. its `vite build`. If there were no build defined. It would have errored out right? But i am able to build it.

Comment: I could tell, as you mentioned `npm init vite` near the end, when it should be one of the first things to note.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "run" an HTML file by clicking it.

If you do not have it served by an actual HTTP server, the scripts/other assets will not be allowed to load. The command `vite preview` should do just that. (Maybe this is already defined as a script in your `package.json`, then you could execute `npm run preview`.)

Comment: I thought the whole point of Svelte was to compile to plain JS that can be ran in the browser?

Comment: @CoredusK: It is compiled to JS, but the JS will not execute if you don't have a proper server (unless the JS is *inlined* directly into the page).